# xampp/lampp not loading memcache

Tags: php, lampp

I've installed lampp 1.8.3 together with devel files from 1.8.1 so that I would be able to install memcache 3.0.8. During both

```
.configure  ./configure -enable-memcache -with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
```

and

```
make
```

there have been no errors. Then I put in my php.ini file command

```
extension="memcache.so"
```

However xampp is failling to load the library.

Comment: And the error message is what?

Comment: When I try to connect to memcache i get the error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function memcache_connect()

Comment: What OS?  I see xampp and .so ?  Isn't that a DLL you want for Windows?  Or this a mac?

Comment: You using repo manager?  Got it with `yum install php-pecl-memcache?`.  Check your logs after restarting apache/php.  You should see a start up error.

Comment: I download a tarball and then installed it manually.

Comment: Where do I check logs? While starting from console everything works well.

Comment: In log i got these messages, any idea how can i recomplie module to fit my PHP ?
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Unfortunatelly I had to reinstall lamp in version 1.8.1 with devel and it works perfectly.